# Is there a way to join metrics on different cased label values?

Tags: devops, prometheus, promql

I have two metrics `metric_a` and `_metric_b`

`metric_a` has a label `title` and the value of it is always lowercased.
`metric_b` has a label `name` and the value of it is the same as first metric `title` value but **uppercased**.

Example:

```
metric_a{title="title1", details="service"}
metric_b{name="TITLE1", task="deploy"}
```

I need query for joining those metrics to get labels from metric_b to reflect on metric_a like this:

```
{title="title1", details="service", task="deploy"}
```

I tried matching it in various way on label, and renaming label to have same label name, but it does not work when one of the values is uppercased.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use [`metric_relabel_config`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#metric_relabel_configs) and the appropriate (`uppercase` or `lowercase`) `action` depending on which label you choose:

```
- job_name: your_job
  metric_relabel_configs:
  - source_labels:
    - "title"
    target_label: "title"
    # regex: "(.*)"
    # replacement: $1
    action: uppercase
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - localhost:8080
```

Thanks to @markalex for highlighting the fact that joining will only apply **after** the reconfiguration; metrics scraped before the change will still have the original case.

Comment: I don't think there are other solutions, because promql doesn't support change of string case.

Comment: Also, this solution has an issue that joining will be available only after reconfiguration. Older metrics will still have different case. (Maybe this should be in answer?)